# valentina db doesn't allow me to use ssh into a postgres even though i can do it normally

Tags: postgresql, ssh

I have a AWS server which I can access using SSH with a .pem key.

Using valentina, i tried to access the postgres this way

[image]

I keep getting a failed Ident message.

I used that same .pem file and ssh into the server.
Used the same postgres user and password to access using psql client.

It works.

What do I need to do to make the Valentina Studio work as well?

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my `pg_hba.conf` to the following:

```
host    all             all             *                       ident
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I can run `psql -U postgres` on the postgres server.

I cannot run `psql -h localhost -U postgres` on the the postgres server.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

This solves the issue

Comment: You should really show the *full, exact text* of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting a failed Ident message.

This suggests that you can in fact ssh in fine.

At a guess, your manual tests are along the lines of:

```
psql mydb
```

which will generally use a *unix socket*, which appears as `local` entries in `pg_hba.conf`.

By contrast your application will be connecting over TCP/IP, probably to a socket forwarded over ssh to localhost. This authenticates with `host` entries in `pg_hba.conf`.

So I think you're testing a different thing when logging in directly.

Try manually:

```
psql -h localhost mydb
```

i.e. force a TCP/IP connection to be used. You'll get the same error, and it's because of your setup in `pg_hba.conf` choosing `ident` as the auth method for `host` connections from localhost, and presumably there's no `identd` running or other mechanism to allow proper `ident`. You probably want to use `md5` auth.

Comment: you are right. i cannot run `psql -h localhost -U postgres`. I have tried md5 and ident. See above question for the update. I still cannot access.

Comment: Okay I solved it. Thank you. You gave me the clue to solve it. :) 

Write this in your answer and I will accept it. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/75995639e575707db5f1

Comment: @KimStacks You were connecting over tunneled IPv6 to 'localhost' as ::1 ?